# Rails routing: namespace nested in a scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, namespaces, scope, url-routing

With Rails 3.2 I have the following in config/routes.rb

```
scope "/:locale" do
    resource :users, :only => [:new, :create]

    namespace :admin do
        resources :specifications
    end
end
```

Users routes works as expected, specifications routes works except index. With a GET call to "/en/admin/specifications" the following error is returned:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"admin/specifications", :locale=>#<Specification id: 1, name: "Check-in", created_at: "2012-04-28 12:10:29", updated_at: "2012-04-28 12:10:29">}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to add this in your application controller:

```
def default_url_options(options={})
  {:locale => I18n.locale}
end
```

It worked for me, I suggest you to read the sections of the I18n guide where to explain how to [set the locale from the URL params](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params).

PS: Welcome to StackOverflow ;)